# spark read csv behaviour with files containing in one case a header and no header for rest

Tags: dataframe, csv, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

airlines is one of a set of public datasets from Databricks.

Here, part-00000 has a header, the others do not.

This:

```
val paths = Seq(
   "/databricks-datasets/airlines/part-00000"  
   ,"/databricks-datasets/airlines/part-00001"
   ,"/databricks-datasets/airlines/part-00011"
   ,"/databricks-datasets/airlines/part-00071"
   ,"/databricks-datasets/airlines/part-00084"
   ,"/databricks-datasets/airlines/part-00101"
   ,"/databricks-datasets/airlines/part-00105"
   ,"/databricks-datasets/airlines/part-00178")   

val df = 
   spark.read.format("csv")
  .option("sep", ",")
  .option("inferSchema", "true")
  .option("header", "true")
  .load(paths: _*)

df.show(10, false)
```

returns for schema:

```
1996:string
8:string
24:string
6:string
1739:string
...
```

However:

```
val paths = Seq(
   "/databricks-datasets/airlines/part-00000"  
   ,"/databricks-datasets/airlines/part-00001"
   ,"/databricks-datasets/airlines/part-00011"
   ,"/databricks-datasets/airlines/part-00071"
   ,"/databricks-datasets/airlines/part-00084"
   ,"/databricks-datasets/airlines/part-00101"
   ,"/databricks-datasets/airlines/part-00105")
...
```

returns:

```
Year:integer
Month:integer
DayofMonth:integer
DayOfWeek:integer
...
```

What explains this difference?

Ran also with 1.0 SamplingRatio.

Seems random, noticed that a file with more columns has preference. If same number of columns, then seems random what will be chosen as headings.

Comment: perhaps the lesson is to provide a schema if not all the files have headers

Comment: Agree and concluded but curious here! @mck

Comment: @thebluephantom my guess is you are expected to read the complete dataset rather than an arbitrary subset of part- files from it :)

Comment: @mazaneicha  I think it is a guess to be honest. See the difference between the twio. Only the first part has a schema it looks like.

Comment: Far as I know, you have no control over which file gets read first. Read the file with a header into one data frame, and all the others into another. Then union them together.

Comment: Quite a bit of guesswork is going on in `CSVDataSource` to infer ds schema (https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/branch-3.0/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/execution/datasources/csv/CSVDataSource.scala#L109), too much to accurately follow :)  Data sampling also adds certain degree of indeterminism.

Comment: @mazaneicha  tried data sampling already... I am assuming that it cannot work and we need to provide a schema and either skip a row or not

Comment: @thebluephantom I meant sampling that happens inside `infer` itself (not every row is tested against potential schema). In general, not relying on inferrence and providing your own schema would always be preferred.

Comment: @mazaneicha  got all that, just noticed. It is not quite logical but this is hoe the data exists on Databricks. Looking to see if I have missed something, NO is the answer. Thx